# Using VSTs to remake a song (with Komplete 10 Ultimate)

Tags: composition, software

Is there a website out there that give breakdowns of sounds waves of old songs that I can try to duplicate/remake using one of my VSTs?

Comment: I don't think anything like that exists...

Answer (score 1):

No "breakdowns of sound waves", but there are plenty of websites that have MIDI files for old songs.  Some are free and others you have to pay for. Typically the file will contain several parts, one for each instrument (bass, guitar, drums, etc.) Once you have the MIDI file you can import it into a sequencer/DAW and use it to drive your VST synth.  Add effects and mix to taste.  You will have to use your ears and experiment to pick the right virtual instrument and settings to make the synth sound as close as possible to the original, but that's a fun challenge/learning experience.

You can search "free MIDI" for example and come up with lots of possibilities.  Here's one: [Free MIDI](https://freemidi.org/)